# Проблема с игровой задачей на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Вот условие:

> Вам необходимо поделить всех нанятых матросов на 2 команды, согласно
>   следующим правилам: те, чей возраст меньше 20 лет или больше 40 -
>   отправляются на первый корабль, все остальные - на второй. Это
>   позволит молодым матросам перенять опыт более старших коллег.

В качестве исходных данных вы получите словарь, где ключами будут выступать фамилии матросов, а значениями - их возраст. После того, как все матросы будут поделены между кораблями, вам необходимо отсортировать их внутри каждого из списков в алфавитном порядке.

Привожу мой вариант решения.

*** P.S.  Не судите строго, только начинаю учить JS.***

```js
function twoTeams(sailors) {
  var first_ship = [];
  var second_ship = [];
  for (var name in sailors) {
    if (20 > sailors[name] > 40) {
      first_ship.push(name);
    } else {
      second_ship.push(name);
    }
  }
  first_ship.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.first_ship > b.first_ship) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.first_ship < b.first_ship) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  second_ship.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.second_ship > b.first_ship) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.second_ship < b.first_ship) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  twoTeams({
    'Smith': 34,
    'Wesson': 22,
    'Coleman': 45,
    'Abrahams': 19
  })
```

Comment: А что, по-вашему, делает эта строчка? `if (20 > sailors[name] > 40)`. И что такое `a.first_ship` в функции сравнения?

Comment: В заголовке упомянута какая-то проблема. В чем проблема?

Answer (score -2):

```js
function twoTeams(sailors) {
  var first_ship = [];
  var second_ship = [];
  for (var name in sailors) {
    if (sailors[name] < 20 || sailors[name] > 40) {
      first_ship.push(name);
    } else {
      second_ship.push(name);
    }
  }
  first_ship.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  second_ship.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  console.log('first_ship = ', first_ship);
  console.log('second_ship = ', second_ship);
}
twoTeams({
  'Smith': 34,
  'Wesson': 22,
  'Coleman': 45,
  'Abrahams': 19
});
```

Comment: Интересны аргументы минусующих...

Comment: Не минусовал, но ответ выглядит плохим, т.к. не имеет ни строчки пояснения ни в чем дело, ни что исправлено, ни как, ни почему.

Comment: @Kromster проблема была решена ещё в самом первом комментарии под вопросом, но не оформлена, как ответ. Ну и никто не торопится с развёрнутыми ответами, зато минусануть время есть. Главное, что вопрошающий уже скопировал ответ и рад-радёшенек. А я рад, что дал правильный работающий код. Собственно, конкретная задача - конкретное решение.

Comment: Согласен с @UModeL, не думаю что из за того что нет комментариев, надо просто минусовать. Можно был бы просто попросить дополнить ответ.

Comment: @Lukas да я не расстраиваюсь. Сижу я здесь ради удовольствия, от того, что могу чем-то помочь людям. Ну, а кому-то нравится минусовать. У каждого свои развлечения))